# npm postinstall script and npm link

Tags: node.js, npm

I have written a module that has a post-install script to perform some tasks.

However, during the development phase of the module, I am using the "npm link" (from within the module directory) and "npm link myModule" (from within the application directory

this has lead to an issue though: the postinstall script needs to read some file from the application directory.

As the module is npm linked, and there is a link in the node_modules directory to the module source folder, the node process that kicks off the post install script has a working directory of the module, not the application.

As a result, the application directory is unknown

Is there a workaround for this ?

**--------update--------**

if I modify *npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js* (https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/2.x/lib/utils/lifecycle.js)  and insert this at line 55

```
 env.npm_start_dir = process.cwd();
```

then I can access the original directory where the user typed "npm link" by accessing

```
process.env.npm_start_dir
```

I would much rather have an "official" way of doing this though